# Keras Model load() with custom initializer

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

I am struggling with a custom initializer and model save / load.

The code looks like this:

```
class ICNR(initializers.Initializer):
def __init__(self, initializer, scale=1, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(**kwargs)
    """ICNR initializer for checkerboard artifact free transpose convolution

    Code adapted from https://github.com/kostyaev/ICNR
    Discussed at https://github.com/Lasagne/Lasagne/issues/862
    Original paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1707.02937.pdf

    Parameters
    ----------
    initializer : Initializer
        Initializer used for kernels (glorot uniform, etc.)
    scale : iterable of two integers, or a single integer
        Stride of the transpose convolution
        (a.k.a. scale factor of sub pixel convolution)
    """
    self.scale = normalize_tuple(scale, 2, "scale")
    self.initializer = initializer

def __call__(self, shape, dtype, **kwargs):
    # super().__call__(**kwargs)
    if self.scale == 1:
        return self.initializer(shape)
    size = shape[:2]
    new_shape = np.array(shape)
    new_shape[:2] //= self.scale
    x = self.initializer(new_shape, dtype)
    x = tf.transpose(x, perm=[2, 0, 1, 3])
    x = tf.image.resize(x, size=size, method="nearest")
    x = tf.transpose(x, perm=[1, 2, 0, 3])
    return x

def get_config(self):
    config = {"scale": self.scale,
              "initializer": self.initializer
              }
    base_config = super(ICNR, self).get_config()
    return dict(list(base_config.items()) + list(config.items()))
```

Very straight forward, ICNR initializer that should take a GlorotNormal() Initailizer as the base class.

```
from models.helpers.icnr import ICNR

layer = layers.Dense(256, bias_initializer=ICNR(initializers.GlorotUniform(), 2))

print(layer.get_config())
```

Works. - But!

As soon as I use the model.save() function or Checkpoint save-callback - I can't load the model because of some deserialisation issues. So far, I know that the problem is that I get a dict passed instead of the GlorotUniform() instance.

Is that a bug, or did I implement doing the get_config() method wrongly?